# Detect User Activity windows phone 8

Tags: .net, windows, mobile, windows-phone-8

My code to start the DispatcherTimer.

I just need to detect any kind of user Ineraction in order to restart the DispatcherTimer?

```
public partial class MainMenu : PhoneApplicationPage
 {
    public MainMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        startTimer();
    }

    private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
    private void startTimer()
    {
        dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        AllMyFunctions.logout_code(this);
    }

    private void restartTimer()
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        startTimer();
    }
}
```

how do i detect any kind of user Interaction in order to fire restartTimer() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an event on the Tap of every PhoneApplicationPage.

```
int timeOutInSeconds;
Timer timerObject;

 private void onPageLoad()
 {
   timeOutInSeconds = 30;
   timerObject = new Timer();
   timerObject.startTimer(this, timeOutInSeconds, appsettings);
 }
private void LayoutRoot_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
   timerObject.restartTimer(timeOutInSeconds);
} 

 public class Timer
{
    public DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
    public PhoneApplicationPage phoneApplicationPage;
    public IsolatedStorageSettings appsettings;


    //public Timer(PhoneApplicationPage callingPhoneApplicationPage)
    //{
    //    this.phoneApplicationPage = callingPhoneApplicationPage;
    //}

    public void startTimer(PhoneApplicationPage callingPhoneApplicationPage, int noOfSeconds, IsolatedStorageSettings calledAppsettings)
    {
        this.appsettings = calledAppsettings;
        this.phoneApplicationPage = callingPhoneApplicationPage;
        dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_time_done);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, noOfSeconds);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
    public void timer_time_done(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        BsgFunctions.logout_Forcefully_code(phoneApplicationPage, this, appsettings);
    }

    public void restartTimer(int noOfSeconds)
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        startTimer(phoneApplicationPage, noOfSeconds,appsettings);
    }

    public void stopTimer()
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    }

}
```